# Use a random record in a file for a preparedstatement

Tags: java

I'm using Swingbench for some load testing. I just have to create a case that runs something like

```
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE COL2 = ?
```

The value of COL2 is a number contained in a file, like a customer number, that is not a sequence. Looking for available classes in Swingbench and demos I see that wherever Swingbench reads a file with (for example) productids, it uses a single product id calculating a random value between min and max value of the file. In my case, this is not applicable.

How can I tackle this problem in Java?

Comment: What format is the file in? http://dominicgiles.com/dgwalkthrough.html seems to indicate that you can specify a file as a source for the data generator and that it will read the file into memory and select a random record from it, but I assume it only works on something like CSV.

Comment: How large is the number of records in the file?

Comment: File contains about 571000  records. Yes you can specify the source and I will specify the source but I am also creating an adhoc scenario cause no provided scenarios fit my needs.